configobj - change fontsize 11 to 8 in ini.file
How do I set the fontsize in the configobj ini.file? I aassume its part of the metadata of the file that needs to be changed. But how?
In MS Wordpad its defaulted to display/print at fontsize 11 (Consolas Regular). In Openoffice writer its 12.
from configobj import ConfigObj

cfg = {'newfontsize' : 8, 'oldfontsize' : 69, 'test' : 'unsuccesful implementing smaller fontsize'}

config = ConfigObj(cfg)
config.filename = 'my_config.ini'
config.write()

The nearest information on this topic I can find is:
https://superuser.com/questions/389550/notepad-styling-the-text-before-the-assignment-in-an-ini-file
but that uses notepad++
